# ref.on, ref.off with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While reading a tutorial on React I noticed the following code.

```
componentDidMount () {
ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  this.setState(function () {
    return {
      friends: snapshot.val()
    }
  })
}.bind(this)
}
```

Where does the 'ref.on' method come from? Is that something baked into React or is it a JavaScript function? I can't find it here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript.  Also, there is 'ref.off' in another place in the React components.

```
componentWillUnmount () {
  ref.off()
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's helpful to know that it may be pseudocode. It's from this course https://learn.tylermcginnis.com/courses/50507/lectures/762618. But you have to login to view it. It's in the section on React Life Cycle Events.

I'm asking about the '.on' and '.off' parts, not the 'ref'.

Comment: What is `ref`? I know `on` and `off` are prototype members in jQuery objects, maybe this code is interfacing with some third-party library.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: `ref.on` is neither something baked into React nor a JS function. It could be something special the tutorial introduced, or it could be that the tutorial is simply using pseudocode. Where exactly did you find this?

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not asking specifically about 'ref' that is well documented. I just didn't know where the '.on' and '.off' parts came from.

Answer (score 0):

ref is a reference to the mounted component. With ref you will be able to access the class methods of the mounted component.

```
class Foo extends Component {

    render() {
        return <span onClick={this.onDivClick}>hi</span>
    }

    onSpanClick = () => {
       // do something
    }
}

class Bar extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.onDivClick}>
                  <Foo ref={c => this.ref = c}/>
               </div>
    }

    onDivClick = () => {
       this.ref.onSpanClick() // reference to the mounted Foo instance and call the method onSpanClick
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.ref` maybe, but `ref` alone doesn't mean anything.

Comment: there is a .bind(this)

Comment: which doesn't change anything for plain variables?

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not asking specifically about 'ref' that is well documented. I just didn't know where the '.on' and '.off' parts came from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery's method for adding and removing event listeners. Probably just using it as an example.